# How to serve static files in loopback 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I am serving static files (client builds) using middleware.json

For client,admin and question admin like this

```
"files": {
    "loopback#static": [
        {
            "params": "$!../client"
        },
        {
            "paths": [
                "/admin"
            ],
            "params": "$!../clientAdmin"
        },
        {
            "paths": [
                "/question"
            ],
            "params": "$!../adminQuestion"
        }
    ]
},
```

I want to add another path like

```
        {
            "paths": [
                "/sponsor/.*"
            ],
            "params": "$!../client"
        }
```

which means that if the url is localhost:3000/sponsor/google or localhost:3000/sponsor/dell, i need to serve the client file.

How to handle this?

I tried this one,

```
    app.use('/sponsor/:id',loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
```

It loading the path but auto redirecting to localhost:3000.

How to handle this dynamic case?

Comment: You tagged it as loopback4 but wrote loopback3 in the title? Which one is it?

Comment: Loopback 3. To get the help from from loopback developers I added lb 4.

Comment: `app.use('/sponsor/:id',loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));` worked fine.

Comment: Great :) Note that you can post this as your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use('/sponsor/:id',loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
```

Worked fine